# Postgresql - Commit not happening when synchronous_commit is OFF

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, stored-procedures, commit

I have a stored procedure in Postgresql as follows -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_flows(records IN text, store IN varchar)
RETURNS Integer AS
$body$
DECLARE
    rowsInserted INT;
BEGIN
    insert into mytable select * from anothertable;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rowsInserted = ROW_COUNT;
    RETURN rowsInserted;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql SET synchronous_commit to OFF;
```

When I invoke this stored procedure through Spring JPA, it runs fine, but later when I check the count of records in mytable it shows 0.

This does not happen if I remove the `SET synchronous_commit to OFF` setting, that is the records get inserted and the count on table reflects the correct value.

Is there anything else that needs to be configured in order to use run a stored procedure with Synchronous_commit flag off?

Comment: Does it work properly when you run this from the psql command line?

Comment: I tried the scenario on psql, it dosen't work on psql either.

Comment: I am sorry about the previous comment about commit failing on psql as well. I tested again, this scenario WORKS with psql, but fails when invoked through JPA.

Comment: `synchronous_commit` doesn't change the semantics of a transaction (from the client's point of view). Only how the data is written _physically_. What is your **exact** Postgres version (add the output of `select version()` to your question). What happens if you use the "plain" insert from inside JDBC with `synchronous_commit` set to off manually?

Comment: and does it "work" with JDBC ?

Comment: `synchronous_commit` might be a red herring. Maybe you have a random bug or a pool misconfiguration that causes the `commit` to not be executed, or not in a timely fashion, or the transaction being discarded.